# Fitting a function in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, lm, nls

I have a few datapoints (x and y) that seem to have a logarithmic relationship.

```
> mydata
    x   y
1   0 123
2   2 116
3   4 113
4  15 100
5  48  87
6  75  84
7 122  77

> qplot(x, y, data=mydata, geom="line")
```

[image: plot]

Now I would like to find an underlying function that fits the graph and allows me to infer other datapoints (i.e. `3` or `82`). I read about `lm` and `nls` but I'm not getting anywhere really.

At first, I created a function of which I thought it resembled the plot the most:

```
f <- function(x, a, b) {
    a * exp(b *-x)
}
x <- seq(0:100)
y <- f(seq(0:100), 1,1)
qplot(x,y, geom="line")
```

[image: plot2]

Afterwards, I tried to generate a fitting model using `nls`:

```
> fit <- nls(y ~ f(x, a, b), data=mydata, start=list(a=1, b=1))
   Error in numericDeriv(form[[3]], names(ind), env) :
   Missing value or an Infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on what to do from here?

**Follow up**

After reading your comments and googling around a bit further I adjusted the starting parameters for `a`, `b` and `c` and then suddenly the model converged.

```
fit <- nls(y~f(x,a,b,c), data=data.frame(mydata), start=list(a=1, b=30, c=-0.3))
x <- seq(0,120)
fitted.data <- data.frame(x=x, y=predict(fit, list(x=x))
ggplot(mydata, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(color="red", alpha=.5) + geom_line(alpha=.5) + geom_line(data=fitted.data)
```

[image: plot3]

Comment: I think the right place to point you is towards a Statistics 101 course. You could at least show us your efforts with `lm`.

Comment: I advise you to read the R manual : type `?lm`, `?nls` and `?formula` in your RConsole

Comment: Sorry for my laziness - I'm a little frustrated right now. I added the steps I did with `nls` and the error it produced.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but have you every tried using `lm(y ~ poly(x, 3), data = mydata)` ? One can try different degrees of polynomial and compare the results of `lm` using `anova`.

Comment: Please edit your question  - you now refer to `f(x,a,b,c)`, which is not defined. What is it? You have  only `f(x,a,b)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe using a cubic specification for your model and estimating via `lm` would give you a good fit.

```
# Importing your data
dataset <- read.table(text='
    x   y
1   0 123
2   2 116
3   4 113
4  15 100
5  48  87
6  75  84
7 122  77', header=T)

# I think one possible specification would be a cubic linear model
y.hat <- predict(lm(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3), data=dataset)) # estimating the model and obtaining the fitted values from the model

qplot(x, y, data=dataset, geom="line") # your plot black lines
last_plot() + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y.hat), col=2) # the fitted values red lines

# It fits good.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try taking the log of your response variable and then using `lm` to fit a linear model:

```
fit <- lm(log(y) ~ x, data=mydata)
```

The adjusted R-squared is 0.8486, which at face value isn't bad. You can look at the fit using plot, for example:

```
plot(fit, which=2)
```

But perhaps, it's not such a good fit after all:

```
last_plot() + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=exp(fit$fitted.values)))
```

Comment: What is the implication of using log on response variable?

Comment: Simply that the OP suspected a log relationship so fitting a linear model of x ~ log(y) is a quick way to check that.

Answer (score 3):

Check this document out: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf

In brief, first you need to decide on the model to fit onto your data (e.g., exponential) and then estimate its parameters.

Here are some widely used distributions:
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm